# How to click link text in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, click

How to click the link text within an iframe?

```html
<iframe id="PaymentFrame" src="http:///AccolentMVC/PaymentGW/payment?0JcINmGD1R3z/YV2fWT/YVRV8qXMPwXxer0Q634aBlT+KRL1LNdyEQtXL0MBOTXGTGdIM+NM/orGjrTKXS3tb5d5HG/6tUtND0JSdhGoAe1Ugk+kk81jR93x7u9aYYRdkluT3xDvNpoaKCaa0XMDmbJ1eFqMx7+7lw7PuFmXcXK5BO9NMUQspCPPIAPTmFJybBBHw4p2L+aHYTEA+FwZ0LTujo+wnhbQZL1qsoB9+xWSw/NOjHb/l+sfmmeMAcrO6SRl6/Rd2aY=" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:475px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title></title>   
<aside>
    <fieldset id="navcontainer">
        <legend><div style="color:#A20F00;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold">Payment Methods</div></legend>
        <div align="center" style="margin:10px;font-size:16;font-weight:bold;">            
            <p>
        Select payment method:        </p>
            <ul>         

            <li style="list-style-type:circle;width:80px;margin:10px;font-size:16;"><a href="/AccolentMVC/PaymentGW/UserData/1?key=Google%20Wallet&amp;key1=Google%20Wallet">Google Wallet</a></li>
            <li style="list-style-type:circle;width:80px;margin:10px;font-size:16;"><a href="/AccolentMVC/PaymentGW/UserData/1?key=gwAuthorizeNet&amp;key1=AuthorizeNet">AuthorizeNet</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</aside>
    </div>
```

We are using this code and it doesn't click the Link text:

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
    //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("PaymentFrame")));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Wallet")).click();
```

Comment: Am getting this errors:Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Google"}

Comment: You should first switch to frame not to default content.

Comment: How to get Switch to frame using(driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("PaymentFrame")));) this not locate

Comment: Using driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Wallet")).click(); or driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Google Wallet']");not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using xPath.

Use below code to click on the link :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("PaymentFrame")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\a[contains(text(),'Google Wallet')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

'Google Wallet' is not present in iframe in the above html sample. You can find it by using simple xpath like below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Google Wallet']");
```